# Gitlab authentication and authorization for single sign-on with Azure AD

Tags: git, gitlab

I have setup gitlab (ce version) and it works fine with Azure AD for single sign-on. However if a account is blocked from Azure AD, it wont allow to access via web page since it always check the Azure AD, But from git (ex git clone) it allows to access via a Authentication Token.

How can I block access to git clone if the account in Azure AD in blocked.

Comment: Is this true? Man... I had hoped they would auto block the same way they did with LDAP sync or is this an CE only thing? Do you have a link to the documentation where they talk about this? This is about Omniauth right?

Comment: You were right... We'll have to swap to LDAP via Azure instead it seems.

Comment: Is there a good document to follow LDAP setup for Azure AD LDAP.

Comment: Well there is a long text, not sure if it is good. I am not that good at it either but I have personnel that must fix this for me (but they are busy atm so can't give any good tips either :( ) https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap/